# How json could transfer data

Tags: json

I have questions regarding json:

1. How could a software locate json file made by other software like how could Firefox locate the configuration of Chrome I mean how would it know?
2. What does mean reconstruct data? I read json is used for that in wiki

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you’re talking about the scenario where Firefox when freshly installed can import configuration from chrome. In that case Firefox just locates that file by convention. E.g. on macOS the conventional file path is perhaps sth like `~/Application Support/Google Chrome/…/config.json` (I made it up). Anyway, it’s just a fixed location.

Reconstruct data, is also called deserialization. The counterpart is serialization.

Data is conceptually just arbitrary information. The format we use to store and transmit information is called “encoding” of data. JSON is one kind of encoding, which is a text-based, human readable format. Meanwhile computer only understands the machine readable format of a bunch of zero and ones. That’s also a kind of encoding.

When some data is encoded as JSON, it needs to be converted from text into zero and ones in order to be useful to a program. This process is “deserialization” or “data reconstruction”. It reconstructs data from a serialized text-based file on hard disk, into bytes loaded in memory.

Comment: What if Firefox wants data from unknown software

Comment: Then it doesn’t know, unless it asks you to provide the location.